# Не находит файл, находящийся в этом же катологе

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++

В данной программе я пытаюсь преобразовать файл так, чтобы в нём оставались только цифры, однако программа отказывается открывать файл под именем file1.txt, хотя он и существует: выходит ошибка No such file or directory.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    char s[150];
    char str[150];
    FILE *f1;
    fopen_s(&f1, "file1.txt", "r+");

    if (f1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Ошибка открытия файла");
        system("pause");
        return(1);
    }
    while (fgets(s, 150, f1) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf_s(s, "%s", str);
        for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            char *string = str;
            size_t span = strspn(string, "0123456789");
            if (string[span] == '\0' && i == 0) 
            {
                int i = 0;
                printf("%s\n", str);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f1);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Файл ищется не в папке с экзешником, а в "текущей рабочей директории". Обычно они совпадают, но если запускать программу из IDE, то текущая директория может быть другой.

Попробуйте создать файл из программы и посмотрите где он появится.

---

Или, если у вас достаточно новый компилятор (с поддержкой С++17), можно узнать текущую директорию:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path().string() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Или использовать std::filesystem, с указанием относительного илиполного пути.

Comment: @Maggot Добавил.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// part 1 из файла 

int main() {
 ifstream input("input.txt");
 string line;
 while (getline(input, line)) {
         cout << line << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}



// part 2 из фаила в файл 

int main() {
 ifstream input("input.txt");
 ofstream output("output.txt");
 string line;
 while (getline(input, line)) {
         output << line << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

попробуйте так прочитать